# scala fast check if string is ip address

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ipv6, ipv4

I am running spark with scala and want to filter out Seq[String] where String might be some domain, ipv4, ipv6, some string or empty.

What will be fastest way to check if string is ipv4 or ipv6?

Right now this is my approach:

```
import com.google.common.net.InetAddresses

val someString: String = ""
InetAddresses.isInetAddress(someString)
```

is there any other faster approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "faster approach"? Validating `IPv4`, `IPv6` and hostnames is done using some specifications, you can try to implement it however you want (either using regexes, or write a function for it or anything else). `InetAddresses.isInetAddress` does the trick for `IPv4` and `IPv6`, you may want to extend it with hostname checking. If you want it to work faster for you, either implement a faster validator, or explain your problem clearer, maybe you can use the same thing with some other data structures and get what you actually want!

Comment: imagine you process million arrays per seconds and each array is of length N and you apply some function of this array filtration. acccesing and processing array in distributed way is well optimized but this single function filtering array is crucial.. you i have my approach mentioned above and i am asking for something more efficient.

Comment: You'd have to do benchmarks by yourself to find the best library or compare libraries to your own code. We cannot answer that. If you do benchmarks, make sure to use right tooling like jmh.

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki then you have to deal with `O(n)`, if you want to make it faster, write a faster function, there's nothing to do with the iteration or data structures.